# Is there a way to left_join two sequences with various dates so that both appear?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr, left-join

I am interested in combining two dataframes with differing dates so that for the first sequence, NAs appear where there is no entry and similarly, this happens also for the second sequence.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),floor_date(Sys.Date(), "month"),"months")-1
seq <- rep(c(1),length(dates))
df1 <- cbind.data.frame(dates,seq)

dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),floor_date(Sys.Date(), "month"),"months")-2
seq <- rep(c(2),length(dates))
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(dates,seq)

DF <- left_join(df1,df2,by="dates")
```

What I get is the third row of the DF are NAs. Desired output would be:

2018-12-31     1   NA

2018-12-30     NA     2

and so on ...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are looking for `full_join` :

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1,df2, by="dates") %>% arrange(dates)

#        dates seq.x seq.y
#1  2018-12-30    NA     2
#2  2018-12-31     1    NA
#3  2019-01-30    NA     2
#4  2019-01-31     1    NA
#5  2019-02-27    NA     2
#6  2019-02-28     1    NA
#...
#...
```